# Installing PHP Github project on localhost using composer

Tags: php, github, localhost, composer-php

I downloaded the [Text-Statistics](https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics) ZIP master from Github and extracted and renamed the folder to stats on `/Library/WebServer/Documents/stats`. Then I used `cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/stats` and `composer update` and all dependencies built on `/Library/WebServer/Documents/stats` as well. When I go to `http://localhost/stats/` in my browser, it shows as follows:

[image: composer, php, github project installation]

This is my first time to install a project on my localhost directory which uses composer. Shall I create an `index.php` to see how the codes work? Below you can also see the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "textstatistics",
    "description": "PHP package to measure the readability of text according to various algorithms.",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "DaveChild\\TextStatistics" : "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-bcmath": "More accurate floating point calculations.",
        "ext-mbstring": "Handle multi-byte text properly."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you 'installed' is a toolbox and meant to be used inside your project. It has no index.php since that would be useless, what would it have to show?

You should add it to an existing project by running `composer require davechild/textstatistics` from your project's root directory.

Composer exists so you do not have to download the package, and it's dependencies, yourself (like you did with the zip). It will also generate your autoload file so you do not have to bother about requiring or loading those classes. And it is especially useful when you want to update your dependencies (just run `composer update`)

Answer (score 2):

This is completely unrelated to `github` or `composer`. It looks like this project is not a web application, because I don't see a bootstrap file (something like `index.php`). This means there is nothing which makes sense to call from a webserver context.

I took a short look at the projects github page. `PHP Text Statistics` is a library that will be used in other projects, but it's not a standalone tool, or application.

Comment: Thank you KingCrunch, your answer is also correct, I wish there was an option to select your answer as a correct answer as well.